# Retry an NSURLSessionDataTask request after re-authorizing (AKA NSInvocation equivalent in Swift)

Tags: rest, swift, nsurlsession, nsinvocation, nsurlsessiondatatask

TL;DR version: What is the nearest equivalent to `NSInvocation` - or similar way to package up a method call, including arguments - in Swift?

Background: I have a `ServerController` object which is used across my app to make requests to an API. The magic happens in this method:

```
    private func makeRequestWithPath(
            path: String,
            method: String = "GET",
            body: NSData? = nil,
            successBlock: (AnyObject?) -> Void) {  
// ...
            self.urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request,
               completionHandler: { (data, resp, error) -> Void in

                 if let httpResp = resp as? NSHTTPURLResponse {

                     switch httpResp.statusCode {

                         case 200:
                             successBlock(/* pass process response in here */)

                         case 401:
                             self.postNotificationOnMainThread(kAppTokenRefreshRequiredNotification)

// ...
            }.resume()
```

Periodically API requests fail with a 401, which gets broadcast in the app as a notification, as many parties are interested in the fact the request is going to take a bit longer. Another API request is used to refresh an app token and then other API requests start working again.

This is the part I need help with: ***I then need to repeat the original API request*** following re-authorization.

Previously in Objective-C I might have used an `NSInvocation` object to package up the original method call, but this is not available in Swift and I'm therefore thinking there must be a more Swift-like approach. However I've not yet managed to get it figured out.

The best approach I've come up with so far is to:

- put the arguments, along with a reference to the `ServerController` into a dictionary and pass them into the notification as the `object:` parameter
- in the notification observer (after completing the re-authorization), pull the arguments out of the dictionary and manually call the same method again to repeat the request

This seems like a sub-optimal solution and there must be better way.